# Getting java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL... But thru browser it works fine?

Tags: java, http, web-applications, http-status-code-403

I have two web application  hosted on two different tomcat instances say T1 and T2. I  am making below method 
in a java class on T1 to retrieve  java object named as User from T2

```
private Properties checkContentChanges() {

Properties reply = null;
try {
    String urlStr = "http://myApp:8080/wiki/bin/view/?checkContent=true&Name=dummy;"
  URL url;
  reply = new Properties();
  try {
    url = new URL(urlStr);
//sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection conn = (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection) url
        .openConnection();//line 1
      URLConnection conn =  url
        .openConnection();// line 2
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();// line3 
    reply.load(conn.getInputStream());
  }
  catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();//line 5
  }

}
```

But at line 3 i am getting error **java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://myApp:8080/wiki/..**. Though the call goes to method on T2 and
it returns expected  user object. But once it return i get above exception at lin 5. I tried line 1 too instead of line 2 but same exception?

**EDIT:-**
Though thru the brower same url works fine

As per different suggestion son net i tried below code too but same error

```
  conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)");
```

Comment: May be because of that semicolon(;) in the end of the url ??

Comment: without semiclon too same result

Comment: Is it possible that a cookie is set in your browser that provides some form of authentication?  What happens when you do `curl http://myApp:8080/wiki/bin/view/?checkContent=true&Name=dummy;` ?